# regEx duplicate character class

Tags: javascript, regex

var regEx = /[24680]d*[24680]/

for this regEx variable I was wondering what does it actually mean for this to have double [24680]. I know d means digits from 0 to 9 to clarify that this sin't just one single number and the * is a quantifier that means if it runs zero or more times in a given string... But why is it necessary to put it twice?

Comment: You can check if you understand the pattern correctly [here](https://regex101.com/r/ENFSsR/1). `d` matches a `d` letter, `d*` matches 0+ `d`s, and `[24680]` just matches any single even digit.

Comment: great website! Thanks!